# U.S. Estate/Gift Tax: If Previously Gifted Asset Is Brought Back Into Estate At Death, How To Account For Prior-Filed Gift Tax Return?

Tags: united-states, gift-tax, estate-tax

This question is about U.S. estate/gift tax law.

Imagine a scenario where a parent gifts an asset to the child, i.e. a $500k house, in an irrevocable grantor trust. It's a "completed gift" in that they file a gift tax return, & use up $500k of their lifetime gift/estate tax exemption. However, the parent also retains a power in the trust that brings it back into their estate at death. Let's say the house is then worth $700k at death.  When it's brought back into the estate at death, the amount of exemption used would obviously be based on the new $700k value.

My question: how does this filing of $700k gift/estate tax actually work at death, in practice? i.e. you filed a $500k gift tax return previously, then it's brought back into the estate at a value of $700k.  How do you account for ("get credit for?") the previously-filed $500k exemption, which it seems is nullified/replaced by the latter $700k one, so you're not doubling up on the use of exemption for this one asset? i.e. we shouldn't use $500k+$700k for the gifting of this asset - just $700k.

(Details/side points: grantor status in the trust could come from i.e. retaining the power to borrow without adequate security.  Bringing it back into the estate could happen i.e. by reserving the ability to delay distribution of income - IRC 2038, & Treasury Regulation 252511-2D says that the mere delaying of the distribution to a beneficiary does not make the underlying gift incomplete.  These details shouldn't be relevant to the crux of the question though, which is simply "if the parent completes a gift to the child & files a gift tax return, but something ends up bringing it back into the estate at death, how do you account for the previously filed gift tax return when filing the new one, with the newer/higher value?).

Comment: Explain how there is "retained interest" if the parents living in a child owned house rent free. Either parents are co-owners with child or child owns house 100%. What names are on the deed?

Comment: Are you sure this is even possible? Can you really have a "completed gift" if you still have "retained interest"?

Comment: @MorrisonChang In this hypothetical, child name is on the deed - my understanding is that the parent living there rent free is considered a retained interest, & there's an IRS code section saying that this is sufficient to bring it back into the parent's estate at death.  This was just an example tho - i.e. another could be the house is gifted to an irrevocable trust with child as beneficiary, gift tax return is filed, but the parent retains some power in the trust that causes it to be brought back into their taxable estate at death. There are various scenarios where...

Comment: @MorrisonChang ...A gift is completed & a gift tax return is filed, but ultimately it is brought back into their estate.  In those scenarios, how do you account from the prior gift tax return filed for the same asset?

Comment: @TTT: Pls see my answer to MorrisonChang, if that clears up the crux of my question? :)

Comment: Basically, there are certain types of transfers that when they're made are 'completed gifts,' but the grantor/donor has retained sufficient interest that under certain tax code sections, when they die the asset is brought back into their estate for estate tax purposes. The question is: when it's brought back into the estate at death, how do you go back & get your credit back from the previously-filed gift tax return, so you're not doubling up on the use of exemption?

Comment: OK. My hunch is only the appreciation would apply at that point. But I'm pretty sure the answer is in [this document](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i709), but I don't have to time to read through it and formulate an answer tonight. (Perhaps someone else can run with it.)

Comment: Yeah, I tried to extract it from there & wasn't able to figure it out either, so was hoping someone with tax experience might know the answer definitively.  Apparently this isn't *that* uncommon of a scenario, just wasn't able to find/figure it out on my own :)

Comment: @Metal450 Please edit your question with information. It would help to link to any article/documentation, as all I'm finding is trust related and that wasn't specified in your question. Also was the gifted house identified on child's tax returns as an investment property or secondary home?

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully more clarify the point I'm trying to address.  Does that help?

Comment: Perhaps it's just my ignorance, but isn't there a logical fallacy here?  If you retain the option to take something back, it's not a gift, it's a loan, no?  So in this case, the parent has not given the child the house, all they've done is to let the child live in it rent-free.

Comment: No, there's a tax concept "completed gift" and "incomplete gift." It's also possible to have a "completed gift" be brought back into the estate at death, per the OP.